# How can I delete an instance of a class within that class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how you can delete a instance within the class. I am trying `del self`, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
class Thing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True
        self.age = 0

    def update(self):
        self.age += 1

    def kill(self):
        if self.age >= 10:
            del self

    def all(self):
        self.update()
        self.kill()

things =  []

for i in range(0, 10):
    thing.append(Thing())

while True:
    for thing in things:
        thing.all()
```

I specifically want to delete the instance inside the class. I have also replaced `del self` with `self = None`, but this statement doesn't seem to have any effect. How can I do this?

Comment: If you could just "delete" an instance, what do you expect would happen to variables that are currently holding that instance? Should they be set to `None` or what? What you're trying to do here doesn't make any sense. If you want to remove the instance from the `things` list, that's easy and doable. But you can't just delete an object altogether while it's still referenced from somewhere else (for example from your `things` list).

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think it should have a similar effect to what `del` does. It should make the variable holding the instance not defined. So if I were to print the `things` list after deleting everything in it, it would give this output: `[]`

Comment: *Why* do you want to delete it? It seems to me that you need a property `inactive` which is `True` when `age>=10`, which is a class-level issue. `del`, on the other hand, manages items in memory. You are asking the garbage collector to do application-level object management for you.

Comment: The instance doesn't know it's a member of a list.

Comment: That isnt how `del` works. `del` deletes *variables* not objects. IOW consider, `x = 42; y = []; y.append(x); del x; print(y)`

Comment: Why, again, do you think it's not working?

Comment: `things` is `list`, so doesn't have an `all()` method. (You're calling `things.all()` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @Martineau I meant to type `thing` instead of `things` in the `for` loop. I fixed it.

Comment: Ethanol: Sorry to say it, but you're still calling `things.all()` in the `for` loop despite your update...`things` is a `list` object, which don't have an `all()` method (which should be causing an exception to occur for that reason).

Comment: Oh what I thought I fixed it. I'll fix it now. Thank you for reminding me, hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do quite what you're asking for. Python's `del` statement doesn't work like that. What you can do however, is mark your instance as dead (you already have an attribute for this!), and then later, filter the list of objects to drop the dead ones:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True   # use this attribute!
        self.age = 0

    def update(self):
        self.age += 1

    def kill(self):
        if self.age >= 10:
            self.alive = False  # change it's value here rather than messing around with del

    def all(self):
        self.update()
        self.kill()

things =  []

for i in range(0, 10):
    things.append(Thing())

while True:
    for thing in things:
        thing.all()

    things = [thing for thing in things if thing.alive] # filter the list
```

Note that the loops at the end of this code run forever with no output, even after all the `Thing` instances are dead. You might want to modify that so you can tell what's going on, or even change the `while` loop to check if there's are any objects left in `things`. Using `while things` instead of `while True` might be a reasonable approach!

Answer (score -3):

I had the same trouble last time. I searched some answers of and got one. You can use `self.__delete__()`. This delete method that has two underscores around it can only delete an object, so you are good to go!!!

Comment: The `__delete__` method is part of the descriptor protocol. It doesn't do what the questioner wanted in this situation.